# Filter for product subcategory listing page load

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, listing

I need to run a code when the subcategory listing page loads in a woocommerce wordpress site.

The subcategory listing page  has route as'

> /product-category/{catgeory}/{sub-category}.

I need a filter which I can hook upon when this page loads and run a code. I could also run the code in the template file of the route. But I can't find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Do this code on `category-archive` template.

1. Fetch queried object using `get_queried_object()`.
2. Check if the parent value in returned object is 0 or not.
3. If it is not 0 then run your code.

   ```
   $category = get_queried_object();
   if($category->parent != 0){
        //write your code here
   }
   ```